# ASP.NET Shopping Cart on Northwind Database

Tags: asp.net

Thank you for the inputs. I have captured the product selection from the shop page in the form of session variables and displayed them on Checkout page. My last step  is to be able to kill a few products on the check out page(incase the customer selected products he did not need). Here is my attempt for the same.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace ShoppingCart
{
    public partial class Checkout : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                CheckBoxList1.DataSource = Session["MySelectedItems"];

                CheckBoxList1.DataBind();
            }

        }

        protected void ReturnBacktoShopping_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Shopping.aspx");
        }

        public void KillOrders()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CheckBoxList1.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if (CheckBoxList1.Items[i].Selected)
                {
                    CheckBoxList1.Items.Remove(i);
                }
            }
        }

        protected void RemoveItems_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KillOrders();
            List<ListItem> selectItems = new List<ListItem>();

            foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList1.Items)
            {
                if (item.Equals(null))
                    selectItems.Add(item);
            }

            Session.Add("MySelectedItems", selectItems);
            CheckBoxList1.DataSource = Session["MySelectedItems"];

            CheckBoxList1.DataBind();


        }




    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using `Session` or by `QueryString`

**By Session**

In your first page:

```
Session["scart"] = items;
```

Then in your next page access the session using:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cart= String.Empty;
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["scart"].ToString()))
    {
        cart = Session["scart"].ToString();
        // do Something();
    }
    else
    {
        // do Something();
    }
}
```

-

**By QueryString**

In your first page:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String cart = "items";
    Response.Redirect("Checkout.aspx?editor" + cart)
}
```

In your second page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cart= Request.QueryString["cart"].ToString();
    // do Something();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ishan. Inorder to display the Checked selected items on the Check out page (or the second page) . How Do I wire the SQLDataSource control and the Checkbox control. my main focus is to somehow display the checked items on first page on the second page.

Comment: Use PreviousPage.FindControl("yourcontrolid") on your other page

Comment: on my other page.. i inserted the code u mentioned above on the page load ..and on the SQLDataSource_Selecting event handler , I inserted   PreviousPage.FindControl("SqlDataSource1");...it gave me a null object reference error

Comment: try if everything works fine on page load event.i mean just move out the code from SQLDataSource_Selecting and do it on page load and than if that works than put event handlers.

Comment: Now i'm getting confused in what you are trying to do, you said you just want to display whatever you have selected on page "Previous" so now why an event handler on "Next" page?

Comment: I have a list of all products on the first page with a checkbox besides every product. A user can check products.I wish to display the checked products on the next page by using session variables.

Comment: Ya so what i can tell u is store all the checked items in a session variable and use that session variable to display the same products.Dont mix up using PreviousPage and session. use sessions only, your work will be done!

Answer (score 0):

**Edited*** OK, here 's the application workflow.

#### Shopping.aspx page

1.set the CheckBoxList1.DataValueField to Northwind product's key

```
CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ProductID"; //on pageload setup Northwind product's key
```

2.parse CheckBoxList selected values (product's keys) in to ArrayList.

3.store the ArrayList in Session. (2-3 already done.)

#### Checkout.aspx page

```
//1.cast the ArrayList that containing product's keys from Session.
ArrayList keys = (ArrayList)Session["scart"];

//2.generate SQL SELECT command parameters (as string) from this ArrayList.
var cartItems = string.Join(", ", keys.ToArray(typeof(string))); //output format "101, 1213, 348, 777"

//3.set SQLData Control SELECT condition to this parameters.
SqlDataSource.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM Products WHERE ProductID IN(" + cartItems + ")";
```

Comment: Hi ai.farfa. I think my code is correct. Its just that on the Checkoutpage I am finding it difficult to display the products selected by the user on the first page. I think it has some thing to do with the wiring of the SQLData Control and Checkboxlist control